# Relations of equivalence

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given the set $A=(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ and the conditions $2R3$, $4R2$, $1R/2$, $1R/6$, $|A/R|=2$.

The relations of equivalence are:

$((2,3,4,5,6),(1))$

$((2,3,4,6),(1,5))$

?

Comment: By $R/$ do you mean "is not related by $R$"?

Comment: @PatrickStevens Yes

Comment: This is the third question you've asked in the last day that shows no effort on your part. The best way to learn from MSE is to try to answer your question, include your attempt, and tell us where you are stuck.

Comment: @EthanBolker My attemp is there *****! I just want someone to confirm that for me.

Comment: OK. The notation you use is not one I've ever seen before. Unfortunately, the "$/$" has two different meanings. The The relation you write is not an equivalence relation. I assume you are talking about the smallest equivalence relation that contains those pairs (or not). That said, I think your answer is right - you can post it with your explanation as an answer to your own question. When you ask more questions please make them as clear as possible.